# Loop through tens to hundreds of thousands locations at multiples times per second

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

Trying to make a minecraft plugin here. I am trying to make a custom ore generator. The generator is cube, it has no exterior walls on the outside and the middle is filled with ores.

When I create a generator I don't save every single location object because every player can have multiple generator and that would be a massive amount of blocks in no time. What I do instead is that I save the min and max location for the border and for that inside cube(Why save both for border and cube? Well I'll explain in a bit) in a Object called CubeLocation that also stores the cubeId.

So I save the cubes in a HashMap<UUID, PlayerCube> - (This is not the id of a player, but i generate a random uuid when creating  each code).

And I also save the Location in a HashSet <CubeLocation

Now for my problem. I need to check if the location of the broken block is inside a cube. What I have at the moment is something like this

```
public class LocationManager {
    
    private HashMap<UUID, PlayerCube> cubes;
    private HashSet<CubeLocation> cubeLocations;
    private HashMap<UUID, PlayerHold> playerHolds;
    private HashMap<UUID, Integer> tasks;
    private HashMap<UUID, UUID> lastKnownGenerator;
    
    public LocationManager() {
        cubes = new HashMap<>();
        cubeLocations = new HashSet<>();
        playerHolds = new HashMap<>();
        tasks = new HashMap<>();
        lastKnownGenerator = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public HashMap<UUID, PlayerCube> getCubes(){
        return cubes;
    }
    
    public HashSet<CubeLocation> getCubeLocations(){
        return cubeLocations;
    }
    
    public HashMap<UUID, PlayerHold> getPlayerHolds(){
        return playerHolds;
    }
    
    public HashMap<UUID, Integer> getTasks(){
        return tasks;
    }
    
    public HashMap<UUID, UUID> getLastKnownGenerator(){
        return lastKnownGenerator;
    }
    
    public String[] isLocationInsideCube(UUID player, Location loc) {
        UUID world = loc.getWorld().getUID();
        int x = loc.getBlockX();
        int y = loc.getBlockY();
        int z = loc.getBlockZ();
        String arr[] = {null, null};
        
        UUID last = lastKnownGenerator.get(player);
        
        if(last != null) {
            CubeLocation cubeLoc = cubes.get(last).getCubeLocation();
            lastKnownGenerator.remove(player);
            
            if(cubeLoc != null && cubeLoc.isInside(world, x, y, z)) {
                if(cubeLoc.isCubeLocation(world, x, y, z)) {
                    arr[1] = last.toString();
                    return arr;
                }
                
                if(arr[0] == null && cubeLoc.isBorderLocation(world, x, y, z)) {
                    arr[0] = last.toString();
                    return arr;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(CubeLocation cubeLoc : cubeLocations) {
            if(!cubeLoc.isInside(world, x, y, z))
                continue;
            
            String id = cubeLoc.getCubeId().toString();
            
            if(arr[1] == null && cubeLoc.isCubeLocation(world, x, y, z)) {
                arr[1] = id;
                break;
            }
            
            if(arr[0] == null && cubeLoc.isBorderLocation(world, x, y, z)) {
                arr[0] = id;
                break;
            }

        }
        
        return arr;
    }

}
```

And this is CubeLocation

```
public class CubeLocation {
    
    private UUID world;
    
    private int minX;
    private int maxX;
    private int minY;
    private int maxY;
    private int minZ;
    private int maxZ;
    
    private int bMinX;
    private int bMaxX;
    private int bMinY;
    private int bMaxY;
    private int bMinZ;
    private int bMaxZ;
    
    private UUID cubeId;
    
    public CubeLocation(UUID world, UUID cubeId) {
        this.world = world;
        this.cubeId = cubeId;
    }
    
    public void setCoords(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, int z1, int z2) {
        //Border
        this.bMinX = x1;
        this.bMaxX = x2;
        this.bMinY = y1;
        this.bMaxY = y2;
        this.bMinZ = z1;
        this.bMaxZ = z2;
        
        //Cube
        this.minX = x1 + 1;
        this.maxX = x2 - 1;
        this.minY = y1 + 1;
        this.maxY = y2 - 1;
        this.minZ = z1 + 1;
        this.maxZ = z2 - 1;
    }
    
    public UUID getCubeId() {
        return cubeId;
    }
    
    public boolean isInside(UUID world, int x, int y, int z) {
        if(!world.equals(this.world))
            return false;
        
        return (x >= bMinX && x <= bMaxX) && (y >= bMinY && y <= bMaxY) && (z >= bMinZ && z <= bMaxZ);
    }
    
    public boolean isBorderLocation(UUID world, int x, int y, int z) {
        if(!world.equals(this.world))
            return false;
        
        if(y == bMinY || y == bMaxY) {
            return (x == bMinX && (z >= bMinZ || z <= bMaxZ)) || (x == bMaxX && (z >= bMinZ || z <= bMaxZ)) || (z == bMinZ && (x >= bMinX || x <= bMaxX)) || (z == bMaxZ && (x >= bMinX || x <= bMaxX));
            
        }
        return (x == bMinX && z == bMinZ) || (x == bMaxX && z == bMinZ) || (x == bMinX && z == bMaxZ) || (x == bMaxX && z == bMaxZ);
    }
    
    public boolean isCubeLocation(UUID world, int x, int y, int z) {
        if(!world.equals(this.world))
            return false;
        
        return (x >= minX && x <= maxX) && (y >= minY && y <= maxY) && (z >= minZ && z <= maxZ);
    }

}
```

This was also why I saved the border separate from the cube. Because I don't want the player to be able to break the border itself but also leave not take the walls into account(Anyways this isn't the problem but I wanted to explain that).

The problem is that every time a block is broken it will check each and every single CubeLocation to check if the location is a generator. That means that every time a block is broken it will do this check every single time (This is why I added the lastKnownGenerator, it'll first check this to see if the player is breaking blocks in the same generator so it doesn't have to do the loop again).

However this does not help if the player breaks blocks that are not inside a generator (For example in a mine, a house or idk) it will do the loop for every single broken block. And this is not even the worst part, the worst part is that BlockBreakEvent (The event that triggers when a player breaks a block) can be trigger dozens of times per second by a single player (If you have enchants on your pickaxe, shovel or axe) and not only that but it can be triggered by multiple players at once.

So image this, there have been like 30k cube placed on the world in total and there are like 30 players with full enchant minning 20 blocks per second each. The means that every second the plugin checks 600k coords per second. This won't do, it's too wasteful.

You also can't save each and every location separate or mark a block with block.setMetadata(key, FixedMetadataValue(plugin, value)); Because you would have to loop through  (Let's say all the generator in our case are 11x11x11 which is 1331 per generator) 30.000 * 1331 which is a whopping 39.930.000 blocks so it's even worse than what I'm doing.

What would be the appropriate method to save the cubes and also check if the broken block is inside a cube. Am I completely wrong with what I was trying to do? Any and all suggestion are welcome!

Comment: Are coords of cube location changing ? or it's just set one time and that all ? Also, why do "+1" and "-1" ? in constuctor ?

Comment: The coords cannot change, might as well make them final now that I think about it. Anyways the +1 -1 is just a middle cube which is just a smaller cube inside. This is the effect that you get (https://imgur.com/a/JQtkDCw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to do multiple things :

1. **Use less variable**. It will not directly fix the amount of items, but it will help in performance. It's also mostly a suggestion than will make the code quickly more readable. For example, you can add position of a center, then store the size. So you require only 5 variables:

```java
public int centerX, centerY, centerZ;
public int sizeBorder, sizeCube;
```

With these, if you have 30k instance, you will economise 7*30000 so 210k var.

2. **Use chunk**. This can really help you. The objective is to store cube according to chunk.

Firstly, you need to get chunk X/Z :

```java
public static getChunkX(Location loc) {
    rreturn floor(loc.getX()) >> 4;
}

/**
 * NumberConversions#floor(double), used by Location#getBlockX(), Location#getBlockZ()
 *
 * @param num the number to floor
 * @return the floored number
 */
public static int floor(double num) {
    int floor = (int) num;
    return floor == num ? floor : floor - (int) (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(num) >>> 63);
}
```

([Source](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/456619/))

Now, you should declare the variable that will contains everything:

```java
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, CubeLocation>> cubePerChunk = new HashMap<>();
```

It's a table of table of an array. You can refer to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-of-arraylist-in-java/) if you want to learn more.

```java
Location myLoc = ...;
List<CubeLocation> allCubesInChunk = cubePerChunk.get(getChunkX(myLoc)).get(getChunkZ(myLoc));
```

Now, you can do what you did with all cube location, but instead of a list of 30k items you will have only item in this chunk, so less than 5 one.

To store values, you should get chunk of 4 points and try to add it in all list. If all points are in the same chunk, you will have the items stored only one time, else it will be available from all chunk where it is. Example of code:

```java
public void loadCube(CubeLocation loadedCube) {
   for(Location loc : loadedCube.getAllXZPoints()) {
      List<CubeLocation> allCubesInChunk = cubePerChunk.computeIfAbsent(getChunkX(loc), HashMap::new)
             .computeIfAbsent(getChunkZ(loc), ArrayList::new);
      if(!allCubesInChunk.contains(loadedCube)) // if not already added
         allCubesInChunk.add(loadedCube); // add it
   }
}
```

Just, about the `getAllPoints()` method :

It's just something that return all points without taking in count Y, such as:

```java
public List<Location> getAllXZPoints() {
    // w is your world
    return Arrays.asList(new Location(w, minX, minY, minZ), new Location(w, maxX, minY, minZ),
    new Location(w, minX, minY, maxZ), new Location(w, minX, minY, maxZ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I modified the HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, CubeLocation>> cubePerChunk map because with your example you could only store a cube but that is a problem because players could in theory put a cobble cube on top of another one so there would be multiple in that chunk. I also tweaked what i tought would do. I must say that I was probably not going to work with chunks so I am grateful.

Comment: Also for the 1st point I must that you are right, I wasn't going to leave it like that in the final product anyway but I was just trying everything I could think of trying to find something that would work so sorry if the code got messy. Thanks again for the help

Comment: No problem, with pleasure. Just, if you will not use chunk, you will use your own X/Z converter ?

Comment: Oh no that's not what I meant. When I said "I must say that I was probably not going to work with chunks so I am grateful." I wanted to say that I most probably would not have thought to use the Chunk x, z values until much later, you've saved me a lot of time and I'm grateful, I also checked the performance and it is marginally better. Do you have discord or something? I would like to have some chats with you about programming and also ask you some questions if I'm ever stuck again in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Some more tips for you dmf, when you're looking for performance here you have two points you can work on, which is memory optimization, basically you're going to use less memory, which is basically what Elikill already told you up here ^^.

The second thing is you use NMS, since you're setting (i believe, a lot of blocks), its best if you access the deepest nms method you can access, you can find some tutorials on the main spigot website on how to place blocks fast(or you could go and look at FAWE src).

Another thing is, to check if the block broken is inside of the cube all you have todo is get the maximum point of the cube, get the minimum point of the cube,
and check if the x of the block is <= max x,
and the same process, for all the coordinates, x y z.

Please do not call .getAllPoints() to just check if the block is inside of the cube, that would be the worst scenario possible you could write.

Comment: Storing two corners is not an issue at all, this won't affect the performance of your plugin in any ways, since its two locations only, the problem is the .getAllPoints(), which will return you thousands of instances of locations, thats the worst scenario, first of all, to reduce a bit more memory usage you'd use BlockPositions and not Locations, since locations have 3 more fields (world, yaw, pitch), I also recommend that you work with packets and pregenerate multi block change packets for these chunks, this way you won't have to even set blocks on the world, you'd just work with OOP.

Comment: The packet scenario is the best one you can work on! (And even able to multi thread it).

Comment: I suggest you to [edit] your post. Also, the `getAllPoints` will be runned only for few items that are on the chunk so it's not a real problem

Comment: Thanks for the advice. getAllPoints would only get called when loading the cubes so that's not a problem. Using NMS to replace blocks, and i'm not very sure on this one, is faster but there is no light update and this is a problem. Something like this works best when reloading a arena after the game is done and everyone is kicked out of the world.